# How adjust the contentView height with PanGestureRecognize?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to move contentView height with PanGesture. I have a storyboard with contentView. The contentView has an auto layout (trailing, leading, bottom, static height) and It has an embedded view controller.

At the moment I move the contentView (the entire contentView moves, see gif) but I need the contentView bottom to be static so that only the height is adjusted with PanGesture.

How adjust the contentView height with PanGestureRecognize?

[image]

[image]

Code:

```
func prepareGesture() {
        let gesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleGesture(_:)))
        childViewController.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
    }

 @objc func handleGesture(_ gestureRecognizer: PanGestureRecognizer) {
        guard let superview = childViewController else { return }
        let translation = gestureRecognizer.translation(in: superview).y
        let velocity = gestureRecognizer.velocity(in: superview).y
        
        switch gestureRecognizer.state {
        case .began: gestureBegan()
        case .changed: gestureChanged(translation: translation, velocity: velocity)
        case .cancelled: gestureCancelled(translation: translation, velocity: velocity)
        case .ended: gestureEnded(translation: translation, velocity: velocity)
        default: break
        }
    }


    
    func gestureEnded(translation: CGFloat, velocity: CGFloat) {
        
       if velocity < -300 && translation < 0 {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0.0) {
                self.childViewController.center = CGPoint(x: self.initialCenter.x, y: 119)
            }
        } else if ...
    }

 func gestureBegan() {
        initialCenter = childViewController.center
    }
    
    func gestureChanged(translation: CGFloat, velocity: CGFloat) {
        childViewController.center = CGPoint(x: initialCenter.x, y: initialCenter.y + translation)
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the problem here like I see that you don't know the way to update the content view height.

Because of you static your height in storyboard so you need to get that layout constraint into your file and change it in order to get your problem solved

[image: Drag it into your file]

Your code will be like this

```swift
// your height constraint
@IBOutlet weak var heightChildViewController: NSLayoutConstraint!

func prepareGesture() {
    let gesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleGesture(_:)))
    childViewController.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
}

@objc func handleGesture(_ gestureRecognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    guard childViewController != nil else { return }
    // get point location in your child view controller
    let location = gestureRecognizer.location(in: childViewController)
    
    switch gestureRecognizer.state {
        case .began: gestureBegan()
        case .changed: gestureChanged(point: location)
        default: break
    }
}

 func gestureBegan() {
    // do nothing
    // because the gesture only work when pan gesture is tap
}
    
func gestureChanged(point: CGPoint) {
    // change the view frame by offset
    self.childViewController.frame = self.childViewController.frame.offsetBy(dx: 0, dy: point.y)
    // then update your height constraint
    self.heightChildViewController.constant = self.childViewController.frame.size.height - point.y
}
```

Then the result just like what you need, just remember to get height constraint from storyboard and update it

[image: Final Result]